# How to remove duplicates in out put using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
    <xsl:for-each  select="../LineItems[References[Type='BlRefNum2']/Value=$LinePro]/ItemAttributes[Type='Department_Description']">                                                        
    <xsl:if test="not((current()/../DivisionIdentifier='LGB') or (current()/../DivisionIdentifier='LGN') or (current()/../DivisionIdentifier='LBW'))">                          
    <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>                  
    <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())"> / </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>                                               
    </xsl:for-each>
```

i need to remove the duplicates value in the output of this code.(select="Value")please help!

Comment: Can you please show your current input XML and the output you expect? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, have a look at [ask] and [mcve], so that we can actually help you get answers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Basically you'll create a `xsl:key` with your grouping key and take advantage from element concatenation behavior: when you join the same node twice, one one occurrence is returned (ie: `count(A|A)` = 1).

Comment: Hi all,Thanks for your advices.i figured out the issue. actually Muenchian method did not work for my issue.it cannot be applied in that case.i just wanted to remove the duplicates in my out put and it comes as a / seperated string. so i used set:distinct function and then i was able to get the desired output.